# Off set android view while using android:layout_centerVertical="true"?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I'm trying to get a view center vertically in android, but I have a imageView at the top that is 75dps, so I need my centered view to be offset from the top by 75dps so it gets centered! Is there a way to do this? I tried using android:layout_marginTop="75dp" but it didn't work! Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried giving the android:layout_below attribute ?

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your view into a ViewGroup (e.g. LinearLayout), then make the LinearLayout centered, and add the marginTop to your view. It should work.

Anyway, it would be helpful if you post also your layout xml.